# How can a Use Case diagram be presented when an actor has two different scenarios?(the exact same actor)

Tags: oop, uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

I have to build an Use Case diagram, but one of the actors has two different scenarios, for example the actor has to either choose one laptop or some laptops.How do I represent that in my Use Case Diagram?

Comment: I wish you a good time on Stack Overflow. If you find questions / answers helpful, give them an upvote / accept.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. From a use case perspective, it does not matter: The diagram must outline the goal(s) of the system under design. So you have to answer: Why would the actor want to choose laptops? To purchase them? To create a repair request? To send them to a recycling project?

Outline the details in another diagram, such as the various choices of the user during the selection process. Activity diagrams are great for that.